# Android Studio: How to keep logcat pinned when running the app?

Tags: android, android-studio, user-experience

I hadn't used Android Studio in a long time. I recently started using it and am facing a UX issue.

As you can see below, I want to always have the Logcat stay at the bottom like so:

[image]

However, every time I run the app, Android Studio replaces it with the `Run` window:

[image]

While trying to figure out how to keep the Logcat always stay, I used the "Split right" and now I have this 2 pane Logcat which isn't what I want:

[image]

I have 2 questions:

1. How can I keep logcat always pinned even when I run app? I don't want to constantly click "Logcat" to open it.
2. How can I get rid of this split pane window?

Comment: @Computable Thank you, both worked. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use logcat in a separate window - use "View Mode" : "Window" or "Undock".

Another option is to modify the Run Configuration under 'Miscellaneous' and check 'Show logcat automatically'.

As far the split window - right click in the split to remove and select 'Close'.